# attr() in CSS can't be used in all the CSS properties, except content

Tags: css

CodePen Example: http://codepen.io/haoyuchen1992/pen/XXXMZK

**HTML CODE:**

```
<li class = "test" profile="url(http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png)" contentDis = "contentDis">
        This is bad!
</li>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.test:before {
  right: -80px;
  background-size:cover;
  content:  attr(contentDis);
  background-image: attr(profile);
}
```

I don't know why the `attr` function works in content property. But for `background-image`, the profile string isn't apply correctly.

--- Solution Found!! ---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

> The attr() function can be used with any `CSS` property, but support for properties other than content is experimental.

other properties are still not supported in major browsers.

Comment: [The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but **support for properties other than content is experimental.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: @j08691 Thanks! I almost missed the ending words.